# PyQt5 ButtonBox Cancel OK always closes dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt-designer

I want the click of 'OK' to run some code and then NOT close the dialog

Ui code is as below. I capture the button click using

```
self.accepted.connect(self.browse_folder)
```

However, what is happening is that as self.browse_folder is called, the main dialog closes. This behaviour seems to be Related to reject / accept connections in a ButtonBox

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,  QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(600, 400)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 161, 41))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel |
                                          QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 561, 301))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
    self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Read A File"))
```

Comment: remove `self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
`

Comment: Those dialog buttons are made to accept or cancel, both actions involve closing the window, why do not you use a simple widget but want that behavior?

Comment: You are a great support here. You are quite right, I did not understand the nature of the Template Buttons.

Comment: Here we are three years later and I have the comfort that lots of other people had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try self.close()

```
class ThermalWindow(QDialog):
"""
This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent, it
will appear as a free-floating window as we want.
"""
def __init__(self,parent,title):
    super().__init__()
    self.parent = parent
    self.resize(400,400)
    self.setWindowTitle('Thermal ' + title)

    buttons = QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
    buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(buttons)

    buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.ok_callback)
    buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.cancel_callback)

    layout = QFormLayout()
    self.var = QLineEdit()
    layout.addRow(title + " :", self.var)
    layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
    self.setLayout(layout)

def ok_callback(self):
    print("OK")
    self.close()

def cancel_callback(self):
    print("Cancel")
    self.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).